# CMakeLists file don't generate .so files

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, oggvorbis

I am trying to implement the lib ogg and vorbis on an Android project using CMake. The code is based on this [repository](https://github.com/vincentjames501/libvorbis-libogg-android). I was trying to build the source following the google's recommendation and a example from OpenCV. The compilation works but the `.so` file is not attached to the APK. Any idea to solve it?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

set(root_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

include_directories(
    ${root_DIR}/include
    ${root_DIR}/include/ogg
    ${root_DIR}/include/stream
    ${root_DIR}/include/vorbis
    ${root_DIR}/libvorbis
    ${root_DIR}/libogg
)

file(GLOB_RECURSE libogg
    "${root_DIR}/libogg/*.c"
    "${root_DIR}/libogg/*.cpp"
)

file(GLOB_RECURSE libvorbis
    "${root_DIR}/libvorbis/*.c"
    "${root_DIR}/libvorbis/*.cpp"
)

file(GLOB_RECURSE org_xiph_vorbis_decode
    "${root_DIR}/libvorbis/*.c"
    "${root_DIR}/libvorbis/*.cpp"
)

file(GLOB_RECURSE org_xiph_vorbis_encoder
    "${root_DIR}/libvorbis/*.c"
    "${root_DIR}/libvorbis/*.cpp"
)

# add our library
add_library(libogg STATIC ${libogg})
add_library(libvorbis STATIC ${libvorbis})
add_library(org_xiph_vorbis_decoder STATIC ${org_xiph_vorbis_decode})
add_library(org_xiph_vorbis_encoder STATIC ${org_xiph_vorbis_encoder})

# configure import libs
set(lib_DIR ${root_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs)

# Add the shared library
add_library(imported-lib SHARED IMPORTED)

# Directory for compiled binary
set(target_DIR ${lib_DIR}${ANDROID_ABI}/imported-lib.so)

# Link libraries on build directory
set_target_properties(imported-lib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${target_DIR})

find_library(log-lib log)
find_library(z-lib z)

target_link_libraries(
    # Specifies the target library.
    libvorbis
    libogg

    imported-lib

    org_xiph_vorbis_encoder_VorbisEncoder
    org_xiph_vorbis_decoder_VorbisDecoder

    # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
    ${z-lib}
    ${log-lib}
)
```

The source code is here: https://github.com/ppamorim/jni_vorbis

Thanks, I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Which library are you wanting a `.so` for? I can see there are 4 `STATIC` libraries, and one `SHARED` library, but it's `IMPORTED`, which means all you're doing is *importing* a pre-existing shared library for use in the current cmake project.

Comment: I am trying to compile these static libraries on a unique .so library. Is it incorrect?

Comment: Please elaborate, I don't understand what you're wanting to do? Are you trying to *create* a .so library? What is the name of the .so library you are expecting to be built?

Comment: @SteveLorimer I gave you the idea to merge these libraries and now I am building each module separatedely. Now I am able to create the `.so` of `libogg` and `libvorbis`. I've updated the repository if you are interested. Sorry for any inconvenience. I am not good with CMake.

Comment: Apologies I still don't understand what you're wanting to do - I believe it may be lost in translation somewhat. Do you want to create `libvorbis.so`? Do you want to create `libogg.so`? Do you want to create a different `.so` file? If yes, what is the name of that .so file you want to create?

Comment: I was trying to compile these libraries (libogg, libvorbis and libvorbis-jni) from the repository that I mentioned before. This repository uses a old-dated build tools for NDK. Now Android Studio says to use CMake + Clang to build the source code. At first I was trying to build this source creating a single `.so` named as anything that includes these libraries (libogg, libvorbis...). But know I discovered a way to compile each library individually and I got success to generate these `.so` files and it is being added on the APK. Thanks!